# What does cv2.dnn_Net.forward() function return exactly?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using `cv2.dnn_Net.forward()` (forward propagation) for the face detecting pre-trained model. However, I couldn't grasp the idea of utilizing the returned variable from `cv2.dnn_Net.forward()` function (which is `detections` variable from below).

```
face_net = cv2.dnn.readNet(face_prototxt_path, face_weights_path) 
image = cv2.imread(args["image_path"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (300, 300),
(104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

face_net.setInput(blob)   
detections = face_net.forward() # cv2.dnn_Net.forward() function

# Utilizing 'detections' variable
confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
```

What does `cv2.dnn_Net.forward()` return exactly and how can they be utilized as `detections[0, 0, i, 2]` and `detections[0, 0, i, 3:7]`?

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.dnn.readNet` takes your weight file and configuaration file of your model to load your saved model.

`net.forward()` - Runs a forward pass to compute the net output.

your detection i.e `net.forward()` will give `Numpy ndarray` as output which you can use to plot the box on the given input image.

Comment: May I ask what the returned `Numpy ndarray` consists of? I understood what its return type is but I couldn't understand what it represents.

Comment: it returns a blob that represents the DNN outputs of the DNN inputs... it should be a multi dimensional array with [S,H,W,C] samples (batch size), height, width, channels - the actual size depends on your network architecture and I'm not sure about the order.